# Copy specific files from one folder to another

Tags: explorer

I hope you might be able to help me. Essentially I have about 300,000 excel files in an external hard drive which is the output from 50,000 simulations. There are various files in the external hard drive folder but the specific file(s) which I wish to copy and paste in my matlab directory are:

result_simulation_xI_byCal_totale %where x is an integer from 1..50000

The rest of the files are extraneous and will not be used for plotting (at least at the moment). I need to copy all 50000 files of the above name to my destination folder.

The source folder is F:\ 
The destination folder is: C:Documents\MATLAB

I have read around but am struggling and hope that someone may be able to help me.

Thanks in advance.

mp

Answer (score 0):

On windows you can do it 2 ways, one is to use the command prompt or black screen mode of the computer if there is one and use the copy command with parameter values and something like a * wildcard character. The second is to use windows explorer and do it all manually in blocks like this - click on the drive letter in the left column showing the devices and some folders, then click on the destination folder you want to copy the files into, next click on the drive letter then folder from where you want to copy the files from. Click on the first filename in the List (best display format for this task), then press and hold down the shift key and then press the cursor down key one at a time or continuously until a reasonable number of files are highlighted, say no more than 50 files at a time, and release the shift key. Now move the mouse cursor into the highlighted part of the list, press and keep pressed the left mouse button and drag the block over to and on top of the destination folder name and you should see a + symbol, keep the mouse steady, then release your finger from the mouse button and the files should then be copied over as shown in a progress panel, then move the mouse away to the right while copying is done. Repeat as many times as necessary this effective but labour intensive method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this question belongs on stackoverflow, but anyway:

Open the command prompt (cmd.exe) and use the following command to copy 50,000 times in a loop:

```
for /l %i in (1,1,50000) do @copy f:\result_simulation_%iI_byCal_totale C:\Documents\MATLAB
```